# Call a static java method of another package from native code

Tags: java, android, static, java-native-interface, android-ndk

For example, let's say that in Android, I need to call the static method `android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`, which returns a long, from a portion of native code. In the `mylib.c` file, I have

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL 
Java_com_mpackage_MyClass_nativeMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){

  jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
  jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls, "android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtime", "(V)J");

  if (mid == 0)
    return 0L;

  return CallStaticLongMethod(cls, mid);
}
```

In the java `MyClass.class`, I have among others

```
static {System.loadLibrary("myLib");}
native long nativeMethod();
```

but when I call it, I get the following error:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(628): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
```

at the declaration of `mid` line. I think this is straightforward but I'm new to jni.

Can someone point out my mistake(s)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like your usage of the JNI API is not proper.
First you should get the class reference of `android.os.SystemClock`.   The obj passed as a parameter, is an object of `MyClass`. You should use `(*env)->FindClass(env, "android/os/SystemClock")` to get a jclass for the SystemClock. Then call `(*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls,"elapsedRealtime", "(V)J");` to get the method id. Take a look at the [JNI tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/) for further details

Comment: I had found this myself a few minutes ago! However, I had to specify the name fo the class like `(*env)->FindClass(env, "android/os/SystemClock")`. Thanks!